# Get Access Token with a call

Tags: java, facebook, api

I'm using facebook4j with this configuration setup:

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
  .setOAuthAppId("*********************")
  .setOAuthAppSecret("******************************************")
  .setOAuthAccessToken("**************************************************")
  .setOAuthPermissions("email,publish_stream,...");
FacebookFactory ff = new FacebookFactory(cb.build());
Facebook facebook = ff.getInstance();
```

Is there a way to get the Access Token directly with a call frome the code?

ES: Token token = getAccessToken();

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately,no.The facebook access tokens needs to be generated as follows:

1: Create an application in facebook with your website url

2: Run this link in your browser

3: Visit the following to generate a new SHORT-LIVED (1 hour) access token:

https://www.facebook.com?client_id=[APPID]&client_secret=[APPSECRET]&redirect_uri[http://APPURL]&scope=manage_pages,read_stream&response_type=token

4: Take that short-lived access token and send it here:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=[APP_ID]&client_secret=[APP_SECRET]&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=[EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN]

5: Then, either in FB’s Graph API Explorer or on your own, visit here:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=[TOKEN]

Although, u can write a customized method to do the above in your code.I am working on it and will keep you updated.